# RSform: How to skip strings in query output if variables are empty?

Tags: php, rsform, joomla-3.10

I have this Code. I don't know PHP, but I got the result I wanted. Almost. As you can see, the output will include empty URL parameters if none are provided. Some fields will always be filled, others not. All code snippets are tested in the PHP scripts called on form process field.

```
$_POST['form'] ['tracking-url'] = $_POST['form']['host'][0] . "/landing/" . $_POST['form']['lottery'][0] . "/" . $_POST['form']['product'][0] . "/?cid=" . $_POST['form']['campaign-id'] . "&hl=" . $_POST['form']['hl'] . "&bp=" . $_POST['form']['bp'] . "&ba=" . $_POST['form']['ba'] . "&btn=" . $_POST['form']['btn'] . "&hr=" . $_POST['form']['hr'] . "&sl=" . $_POST['form']['sl'] . "&alert=" . $_POST['form']['alert'] . "&l=" . $_POST['form']['l'] . "&wbkz=" . $_POST['form']['wbkz'] . "&coupon-set=" . $_POST['form']['coupon'] . "&utm_source=" . $_POST['form']['utmsource'] . "&utm_medium=" . $_POST['form']['utmmedium'] . "&utm_campaign=" . $_POST['form']['utmcampaign'];
```

Eg resulting in this:
`https://www.domain.tls/page/?id=0251&hl=&bp=&ba=&btn=&hr=&sl=&alert=&l=**&wbkz=12345&coupon123&utm_source=dsdgsd&utm_medium=gsdgsdg&utm_campaign=150_dsdgsd_gsdgsdg_traumjoker_0251`

How can I output only the url parameters with their values if they are available?

I tried something like this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['form']['host'][0])) {
  $tracking_url = $_POST['form']['host'][0] . "/landing/";
 
  if (!empty($_POST['form']['lottery'][0])) {
    $tracking_url .= $_POST['form']['lottery'][0] . "/";
   
    if (!empty($_POST['form']['product'][0])) {
      $tracking_url .= $_POST['form']['product'][0] . "/?cid=";
     
      if (!empty($_POST['form']['campaign-id'])) {
        $tracking_url .= $_POST['form']['campaign-id'];
      }
      if (!empty($_POST['form']['hl'])) {
        $tracking_url .= "&hl=" . $_POST['form']['hl'];
      }
      if (!empty($_POST['form']['bp'])) {
        $tracking_url .= "&bp=" . $_POST['form']['bp'];
      }
      if (!empty($_POST['form']['ba'])) {
        $tracking_url .= "&ba=" . $_POST['form']['ba'];
      }
      if (!empty($_POST['form']['btn'])) {
        $tracking_url .= "&btn=" . $_POST['form']['btn'];
      }
      if (!empty($_POST['form']['hr'])) {
        $tracking_url .= "&hr=" . $_POST['form']['hr'];
      }
      if (!empty($_POST['form']['sl'])) {
        $tracking_url .= "&sl=" . $_POST['form']['sl'];
      }
      if (!empty($_POST['form']['alert'])) {
        $tracking_url .= "&alert=" . $_POST['form']['alert'];
      }
      if (!empty($_POST['form']['l'])) {
        $tracking_url .= "&l=" . $_POST['form']['l'];
      }
      if (!empty($_POST['form']['wbkz'])) {
        $tracking_url .= "&wbkz=" . $_POST['form']['wbkz'];
      }
      if (!empty($_POST['form']['coupon'])) {
        $tracking_url .= "&coupon-set=" . $_POST['form']['coupon'];
      }
      if (!empty($_POST['form']['utmsource'])) {
        $tracking_url .= "&utm_source=" . $_POST['form']['utmsource'];
      }
      if (!empty($_POST['form']['utmmedium'])) {
        $tracking_url .= "&utm_medium=" . $_POST['form']['utmmedium'];
      }
      if (!empty($_POST['form']['utmcampaign'])) {
        $tracking_url .= "&utm_campaign=" . $_POST['form']['utmcampaign'];
      }
    }
  }
}

echo $tracking_url;
```

And this:

```
$_POST['form']['tracking-url'] = '';

if (!empty($_POST['form']['host'][0])) {
    $tracking_url .= $_POST['form']['host'][0];
}

if (!empty($_POST['form']['lottery'][0])) {
    $tracking_url .= "/landing/" . $_POST['form']['lottery'][0];
}

if (!empty($_POST['form']['product'][0])) {
    $tracking_url .= "/" . $_POST['form']['product'][0];
}

$params = array(
    'cid',
    'hl',
    'bp',
    'ba',
    'btn',
    'hr',
    'sl',
    'alert',
    'l',
    'wbkz',
    'coupon',
    'utmsource',
    'utmmedium',
    'utmcampaign'
);

foreach ($params as $param) {
    if (!empty($_POST['form'][$param])) {
        $tracking_url .= '&' . $param . '=' . $_POST['form'][$param];
    }
}
```

None of them work, the output is empty. As I don't know PHP I'm sure I'm missing something trivial.

I tried several solutions and asked in forums. I exspect a tracking url with only the parameters for which are values provided. If there are no values provided, they should be skipped in the output, resulting in a shorter and cleaner URL.

++++++++++++++++++++

SOLUTION:

```
$url_parameters = array(
    'cid' => $_POST['form']['campaign-id'],
    'hl' => $_POST['form']['hl'],
    'bp' => $_POST['form']['bp'],
    'ba' => $_POST['form']['ba'],
    'btn' => $_POST['form']['btn'],
    'hr' => $_POST['form']['hr'],
    'sl' => $_POST['form']['sl'],
    'alert' => $_POST['form']['alert'],
    'l' => $_POST['form']['l'],
    'wbkz' => $_POST['form']['wbkz'],
    'coupon-set' => $_POST['form']['coupon'],
    'utm_source' => $_POST['form']['utmsource'],
    'utm_medium' => $_POST['form']['utmmedium'],
    'utm_campaign' => $_POST['form']['utmcampaign']
);

$url_params = array();

foreach ($url_parameters as $key => $value) {
    if (!empty($value)) {
        $url_params[] = $key . "=" . $value;
    }
}

$tracking_url = $_POST['form']['host'][0] . "/landing/" . $_POST['form']['lottery'][0] . "/" . $_POST['form']['product'][0] . "/?" . implode('&', $url_params);
$_POST['form']['tracking-url'] = $tracking_url;
```

Comment: We should certainly see an array of data populated before calling `http_build_query()` to reliably generate a perfectly formatted query string.